# Is there a specific verb to say "my shoes are hurting me"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, translation

In my native Romanian there is an expression that literally means "my shoes are *beating* me" when they hurt, and thus are producing pain, abrasion of the skin and calluses (*mă bat pantofii*). The use of the verb "to beat" was maybe originally metaphorical but now is descriptive. The verb "to beat" has simply gained a new specific meaning.

I know one can say in English "my shoes are too tight" or "not broken in yet". But is there a specific similar expression saying what the shoes are "doing" to me?

(I have realized I don't know this when for [other purposes](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/19119/3284) I have looked into some Latin/Romance etymologies and the semantic relation between violent action (to beat, to kick), the act of walking and that of creating/opening a path.)

Comment: People say metaphorically that their shoes are *killing* them.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - metaphorically, yes, but do they say it for lack of a specific descriptive expression? The "beating" part in Romanian was maybe originally metaphorical but now is descriptive. The verb "to beat" has simply gained a new specific meaning.

Comment: Shoes hurt for being too tight or loose, holding sweat and causing blisters, walking too far.

Comment: What's wrong with "my shoes are hurting me", as in the heading? It's idiomatic. Aside from that you would describe the particular characteristic of the discomfort: whether they were too tight, too loose (and hence rubbing), ill-fitting, falling apart, letting water in, etc. I'm not sure *why* you want a different expression - are you just curious of all the different ways English-speakers talk about their shoes?

Comment: @StuartF - It's just that my native expression struck me as odd and also as very specific, unlike the very clear "hurt", which of course is fine with me: I was just asking maybe I was missing something or other.

Comment: "My shoes are not broken yet" does not really make sense in English. You meant to say "my shoes are not broken *in* yet".

Comment: @Pilcrow - Yes, of course. I will correct that in the question.

Answer (score 14):

Idiomatically, in English we usually assign the cause of the discomfort to our own body parts...

[image]

...and for an even more extreme choice where the "less common" version is too rare to show on the chart...

[image]

The speaker *might* need to clarify the cause (*My new shoes are too tight*, rather than *I've been on my feet for hours*). But when people are complaining about feeling uncomfortable, they often welcome the chance to use more words anyway!

Comment: But in the other answers specialized verbs are mentioned: to pinch, to wring, and to chafe. How popular is their use and how is it dependent on British vs American and other areas of English?

Comment: While "my feet are killing me" could be caused by your shoes, it can often be due to physiological problems, so I don't think it's equivalent to "my shoes are killing me"

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Verbs like *pinch, chafe, squeeze, rub,...* do exist,, and *could* be used in your context. But hopefully it's obvious to you why *no-one* says *My feet are **pinching** me*. And if you want to sound like a native speaker (the normal goal for learners, even if they never expect to actually *get* that far! :) you only really need to note which verbs ***are*** acceptable for both *the thing **causing** pain* AND *the place / body part that **hurts***. Note that this isn't really an aspect of English usage that's much affected by which side of the pond you live.

Comment: @Barmar: I already pointed out that clarification *might* be needed. But my charts should be enough to convince anyone that if OP wants to soud like a native Anglophone, *he's asking the wrong questioon*.

Comment: @cipricus An Australian English speaker’s perspective: I completely agree with FumbleFingers. Specific verbs like *pinch*, *chafe* are appropriate for describing the **mechanism** of the pain, but if you just want to say “I am experiencing discomfort in my feet/neck/stomach/islets of Langerhans”, it’s perfectly normal and idiomatic to put the body part as the actor.

Comment: @TimPederick - If hit on the head is an English speaker idiomatically inclined to say "my head is hurting"? Maybe my question was not clear but what I want to know is not what people generally say when they feel that kind of discomfort but what they say when they want to describe what they shoes *do*, when they *want* to talk about their shoes.

Comment: @cipricus: A native speaker *might* say *My shoes are too tight / small / loose*, but that's not a very likely utterance (why did you *buy* them if they're not the right size?). The important point is that although it sounds as if *in your native tongue* you're likely to describe the situation in terms of *bad things your shoes are doing to you*, in English we're more likely to describe things in terms of *how we (or parts of us) react to those bad things*.

Comment: @cipricus “My head is hurting” is fine, as is “my head hurts”. “My hat is hurting me” would not be. What I mean is, it’s perfectly grammatical and understandable, but it *sounds unusual*. You need to specify *in what way* the hat (or shoe) is causing pain (“pinching” if it’s tight, “chafing” if it’s abrading the skin, etc.) in order to sound natural and colloquial. The hyperbole “killing” is an exception (“my hat is killing me” is fine), but as FumbleFingers shows, even that is more likely to be used of the body part (“my head is killing me”).

Answer (score 10):

*Pinch* is a specific verb for hurting shoes.

> if shoes or clothes pinch, they hurt you because they fit too tightly
>
> [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pinch_1)

*Wring* has this specific sense also beside its usual and common sense and it is an uncommon alternative to *pinch*, used in British English. *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230711?rskey=On673q&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)* provides this specific sense of *wring* as below, although there aren't any contemporary citations.

> Of a tight shoe or boot: to press painfully upon (the foot, toe, etc.); to hurt (a person) in this way; = pinch *v.* 1b.

*Pinch* is used figuratively also in the phrase *where the shoe pinches* (and its variants) for the source of a trouble, difficulty etc. The uncommon alternative is *where the shoe wrings*.

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I think that if you used "wring" to mean your clothing was uncomfortable, you would not be understood.  Wring means to squeeze water out of something; if you used it in connection with clothing, people would think you were talking about laundry.

Comment: @fluffysheap Yes, the verb _wring_ has the usual sense that you've mentioned but it has this specific sense also, same as _pinch_. I've mentioned as less common, and it is used in British English. I've updated my answer to make it clear. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think the apposite verb for the above description is **chafe**.

> To *chafe* is to irritate or annoy. If your shoes chafe you, they rub your skin raw. Ouch.

[Vocabulary.com]

Per The Britannica Dictionary:

> to cause soreness or damage by rubbing against something (such as your skin)

*If my boots aren't laced up tight they chafe.*

Comment: The thing about chafing is that you need skin.

Comment: Is "my boots chafe" really correct? I think it's not an intransitive verb (for this meaning), it has to have an argument (the thing that it is chafing): "My boots chafe me".

Comment: It's correct to use chafe intransitively, but it might not be what is meant.  Chafe specifically means to irritate by rubbing against.  There are other ways that shoes could hurt.  I once had a shoe nail come up and the head of the nail poked into the sole of my foot.  This didn't chafe, but it hurt.  You would typically use chafe transitively only if you needed to specify a particular body part that was irritated: "My boot is chafing my big toe."

Comment: The OP has mentioned _abrasion of the skin_ in his question. _chafe_ is the appropriate verb for that. Apparently, the OP is looking for a catch-all term, which I doubt does exist at all.